# Micro-services and AWS-IoT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, microservices, aws-iot

[image]

I am planning to use AWS IoT for my devices in the field to connect to my micro services in the cloud.
Idea here is, the devices will publish to the topics that the micro-services will subscribe to. And the microservices will publish to the topics that the device subscribes to.

So, for example, there are 2 devices d1 and d2. And 2 microservices ms1 and ms2.
d1 will subscribe to devices/d1 topic
d2 will subscribe to devices/d2 topic
and,
ms1 will subscribe to services/ms1 topic
ms2 will subscribe to services/ms2 topic

When d1 wants to send information to ms1, then d1 will publish on to services/ms1 topic and to send information to ms2, d1 will publish on to services/ms2 topic etc.
Similarly, when ms1 wants to send information to d1, ms1 will publish on to devices/d1 topic etc
I attached an image on how I visualize it.

My concern here is, a micro service can have multiple instances running at the same time. So all the instances of ms1 will subscribe to services/ms1 topic. And when a device publishes a message on to that topic, how do we make sure only one instance to process that message and not multiple instances?
I understand one of the ways to handle this is to use Lambda, where the message gets passed to lambda, and Lambda can call a REST API on the microservice. However, Lambda might have limitations to the scale I would like to achieve (100,000 devices with 1000 messages each every hour).

So, wanted to see if there is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend taking the time to become familiar with [all the actions available](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-rule-actions.html) in AWS IoT. You mentioned using Lambda as an intermediary service, but rightly pointed out there could be possible issues there. Two services that would work better for your use case are Kinesis and SQS. You could configure your IoT topics to send messages to either a Kinesis stream or an SQS queue, and then your microservices could subscribe to those so that they could process messages individually instead of each microservice instance receiving a copy of every message.